# Android ToggleButton pause/resume issue with start/stop

Tags: android-activity, togglebutton, onresume, onpause

on this activity start/stop siren work perfectly. But siren play and I come back on this activity toggle button display start and click on that another siren play. It means two siren play.

Main Activity.java

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        mp.start();
        mp.setLooping(true);

    } else {
        mp.pause();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sp = SirenActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(
        "my_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = sp.edit();
    spEditor.putBoolean("ToggleButton", true);
    spEditor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onStart();
    SharedPreferences sp = SirenActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(
        "my_settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean ToggleButtonState = sp.getBoolean("ToggleButton", true);
}
```

Comment: hi rtruszk please help me.